# Problem in limits formula for sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the following formulae applicable to limits of sequences:-

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}^{p} = [\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}]^p \qquad $$

The above is given across all texts in the above format.This is also given https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties here as it is .

Just wanted to ask the community that in the above limit , is there a assumed notion that the limit of $a_n$ is positive ?

It can be possible that $a_n$ < 0 and p = $\frac{1}{2}$ , in which case it is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a certain assumption has to be made to ensure that this property (as well as the other properties listed on that Wikipedia page) is true. And this assumption is stated there immediately before the list of properties:

> Some other important properties of limits of real sequences include the following **(provided, in each equation below, that the limits on the right exist)**.

I added the boldface to emphasize the important part.

In other words, what the property says: if both limits exist, then they are equal to each other. But existence of both must be established first. In general, existence of one of them does ***NOT*** imply existence of the other.

---

Also, I intentionally said "in general" above. To make perfectly rigorous statements, we can look more closely at a property and consider and state various cases that make existence implications one way or the other true. For example, look at another property from that list:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n\cdot b_n)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\right).$$
If both limits on the right exist, then the limit on the left exists and the equality holds. But if know only that the limit on the left exists, we can ***NOT*** deduce whether the two limits on the right exist.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer the problem .

Answer (score 0):

What's actually going on here is that limits commute with continuous functions: in other words, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n).$$ This implicitly assumes that $f$ is continuous at the limit; the function in question here is $f(x) = x^p$. In your final sentence, this is not the case.

Comment: Since this is tagged "real analysis" and the Wikipedia link says $a_n$ is a real sequence, the problem may be that here $f(x)=x^p$ may not be defined for negative $x$ with most non-integer $p$

Comment: Sure, so would it suffice to assume that $f$ is continuous at each point of the sequence?